# https request doesn't work in phonegap-iphone app

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am trying to call https request in phonegap-iphone app using jquery's method`getJSON()`.

It works fine in normal safari, but in mobile safari, It gives error like `"Download Failed-Safari cannot download this file"`.

Comment: did you add the cert to your phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occur because the desired server has invalid certificate!
the https server must have valid secure certificate.