# run https request in phone gap

Tags: iphone, cordova

i am developing phone-gap app in iphone and i want to access https (json)request using JQuery.getJSON(url,function),but only in application it does not return any thing but in normal mobile safari it works fine ,though it is working fine as http request in phone-gap app,but i want to work it as https for security reason,please help me.

Comment: Seems similar to [
why not https json request(rest services) does not work in phonegap (iphone) app?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236787/why-not-https-json-requestrest-services-does-not-work-in-phonegap-iphone-app) from a couple hours ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of my problem.As I was running the phone-gap application using iphone sdk 3.2 then i was not able to access https(json) request but when I updated iPhone sdk from 3.2 to 4.0 it is started working fine.Now I am able to get response from https request also in phone-gap applications.