# iOS Phonegap application using XMLHTTPRequest to post to secured webservice call returns status as 0

Tags: jquery, ios, xmlhttprequest, cordova

I am developing an iOS app using phone gap and am stuck at a point.
 When I try to access a webservice using XMLHTTPRequest() I get an status as 0. When I watch this request in fiddler I see that there is proper response.

I have already looked at links stating the PhoneGap app are not restricted by same-origin policy. But I still fail to resolve this issue.

The only difference I could see was that the url I am accessing is secured https. Is there anything like requests to https are not allowed crossdomain.

Please help. I am stuck here for a whole day today.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the certificate of the https webservice you are pointing to is self-signed?

If so, there is no way use anything but a secure known certificate with PhoneGap ajax calls.

See: [https request doesn't work in phonegap-iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236787/why-not-https-json-requestrest-services-does-not-work-in-phonegap-iphone-app)

Another option could be related to your version of XCode: [run https request in phone gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238136/run-https-request-in-phone-gap)